# How To Add Hyperlinks To Pop up menu in Visual Basic?

Tags: excel, vba, popupmenu

How do I make one of the menu items open a hyperlink?

For example say Button 1 when selected in the menu opens "[www.google.com](http://www.google.com)" and Button 2 opens "[www.yahoo.com](http://www.yahoo.com)" instead of test Macro. I tried changing the `.OnAction` to `.FollowHyperlink`.

I even tried just entering the hyperlink in the `.OnAction` section with no luck.

Any advice?

```
Option Explicit

Public Const Mname As String = "MyPopUpMenu"

Sub DeletePopUpMenu()
    ' Delete the popup menu if it already exists.
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.CommandBars(Mname).Delete
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub

Sub CreateDisplayPopUpMenu()
    ' Delete any existing popup menu.
    Call DeletePopUpMenu

    ' Create the popup menu.
    Call Custom_PopUpMenu_1

    ' Display the popup menu.
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.CommandBars(Mname).ShowPopup
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub

Sub Custom_PopUpMenu_1()
    Dim MenuItem As CommandBarPopup
    ' Add the popup menu.
    With Application.CommandBars.Add(Name:=Mname, Position:=msoBarPopup, _
         MenuBar:=False, Temporary:=True)

        ' First, add two buttons to the menu.
        With .Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton)
            .Caption = "Button 1"
            .FaceId = 71
            .OnAction = "'" & ThisWorkbook.Name & "'!" & "TestMacro"
        End With

        With .Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton)
            .Caption = "Button 2"
            .FaceId = 72
            .OnAction = "'" & ThisWorkbook.Name & "'!" & "TestMacro"
        End With

        ' Next, add a menu that contains two buttons.
        Set MenuItem = .Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlPopup)
        With MenuItem
            .Caption = "My Special Menu"

            With .Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton)
                .Caption = "Button 1 in menu"
                .FaceId = 71
                .OnAction = "'" & ThisWorkbook.Name & "'!" & "TestMacro"
            End With

            With .Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton)
                .Caption = "Button 2 in menu"
                .FaceId = 72
                .OnAction = "'" & ThisWorkbook.Name & "'!" & "TestMacro"
            End With
        End With

        ' Finally, add a single button.
        With .Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton)
            .Caption = "Button 3"
            .FaceId = 73
            .OnAction = "'" & ThisWorkbook.Name & "'!" & "TestMacro"
        End With

    End With
End Sub

Sub TestMacro()
    MsgBox "Hi there!"
End Sub
```

Comment: Shiva  - Thanks for the edit. I was just doing the amendments you spotted (already noticed them) and you beat me to the punch. ^_^

Comment: Hi Neo, you don't appear to be displaying your menu bar (at least for Excel 2007+ you need to edit the ribbon). Are you using Excel 2000 /03?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put

```
ThisWorkbook.FollowHyperlink "http://......"
```

In your TestMacro

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to use this as a method of launching hyperlinks, add a parameter to the `Testmacro` sub procedure.

```
.OnAction = "'" & ThisWorkbook.Name & "'!" & "TestMacro(1)"
...
.OnAction = "'" & ThisWorkbook.Name & "'!" & "TestMacro(2)"
...
.OnAction = "'" & ThisWorkbook.Name & "'!" & "TestMacro(3)"
```

The actual `TestMacro` sub would institute a [Select Case statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278665.aspx) to handle all of the menu commands.

```
Sub TestMacro(Optional iTYP As Long = 1)
    Select Case iTYP
        Case 1
            MsgBox "option 1"
            ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink "http://www.google.com"
        Case 2
            MsgBox "option 2"
            ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink "http://www.yahoo.com"
        Case 3
            MsgBox "option 3"
            ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink "http://www.bing.com"
        Case Else
            ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink "http://stackoverflow.com"
    End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Awesome. I never thought of doing it this way.  I have figured out adding another menu that appears from the context menu. It's in the code section.  ' Next, add a menu that contains two buttons.is it possible to add a third and fourth menu beffore the buttons?

Answer (score 1):

as with Bas answer you can set your TestMacro to have an input string for the url and then pass that when calling it

```
' Finally, add a single button.
    With .Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton)
        .Caption = "Button 3"
        .FaceId = 73
        .OnAction = "'" & ThisWorkbook.Name & "'!" & "TestMacro(" & Chr(34) & "http://www.google.com" & Chr(34) & ")"
    End With



Sub TestMacro(url As String)
    ThisWorkbook.FollowHyperlink url
End Sub
```